# Function only works on the first spawned sprite and not the other

Tags: ios, swift, function, sprite-kit

Im new to programming and still learning much. I have just encountered a problem. The part I have a problem with is the sharkWall() function that makes the "SHARKNODE"-sprite turn around and head the opposite direction whenever it reaches the end of the screen in each way. the "SHARKNODES" are spawned every 0.75sec with a timer in Y-direction. And here is the problem. The sharkWall() function only seem to be working on the first spawned "SHARKNODE"-sprite and not the other ones that gets spawned higher up on the Y-axis. Worth to mention is that the first spawned sprite is the only sprite that is visible on the screen until the player gets higher upp on the Y-axis and the other "SHARKNODE"-sprites appear on the screen. And of course, what i want is to make the sharkWall() function to work on all "SHARKNODE"-sprites.
Anyone who has an idea on what to do here and could explain? Thanks in advance.

**GameScene.swift:**

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


var background:SKNode!
var midground:SKNode!
var foreground:SKNode!

var buttonPressed = 0

 var leftButtonFirst: UIButton!
 var rightButtonFirst: UIButton!

var hud: SKNode!
var scaleX = 0
var sharkSprite = SKSpriteNode()

var counter = 1
var player: SKNode!

var scaleFactor:CGFloat!

var startButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "TapToStart")

var endOfGamePosition = 0

let montionManager = CMMotionManager()

var xAcceleration:CGFloat = 1

var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode!
var flowerLabel: SKLabelNode!

var playersMaxY:Int!

var GameOver = false

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

override init(size: CGSize){
    super.init(size: size)

    backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: (57/255.0), green: (214/255.0), blue: (255/255.0), alpha: 1.0)

    scaleFactor = self.size.width / 200


    background = createBackground()
    addChild(background)

    midground = createMidground()
    addChild(midground)

    foreground = SKNode()
    addChild(foreground)

    player = createPlayer()
    foreground.addChild(player)



    var bubbleTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.75, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.bubbleMaker), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    var sharkTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.75, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.sharkMaker), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -3)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

   }



func bubbleMaker() {
    let randomXPos = arc4random_uniform(172) + 15
    let yPosition = CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 200 * CGFloat(counter)
    counter += 1
    let platformNode = createPlatformAtPosition(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(randomXPos), y: yPosition - 180), ofType: PlatformType.normalBubble)
    foreground.addChild(platformNode)


}


func sharkMaker() {
let randomXPos = arc4random_uniform(170) + 10
let yPosition = CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 200 * CGFloat(counter)
counter += 1
let shark = createSharkAtPosition(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(randomXPos), y: yPosition - 180), ofType: SharkType.normalShark)
foreground.addChild(shark)

}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if player.physicsBody!.dynamic {
        return
    }

    player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = CGFloat(500)
    createLeftButton()
    createRightButton()

    createLeftButtonFirst()
    createRightButtonFirst()

}

override func didSimulatePhysics() {

    if player.position.x < -10 {
        player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(3, 0))
    }else if (player.position.x > self.size.width + 10) {
          player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(-3, 0))
    }
    sharkWall()
}


func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var otherNode:SKNode!

    if contact.bodyA.node != player {
        otherNode = contact.bodyA.node
    } else {
        otherNode = contact.bodyB.node
    }

    (otherNode as! GenericNode).collisionWithPlayer(player)
}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {





    foreground.enumerateChildNodesWithName("PLATFORMNODE"){ (node, stop) -> Void in
        let platform = node as! PlatformNode
        platform.shoudRemoveNode(self.player.position.y)
    }

    if player.position.y > 200 {
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -((player.position.y - 200)/10))
        midground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -((player.position.y - 200)/4))
        foreground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -((player.position.y) - 200))
    }
}


func sharkWall(){
if foreground.childNodeWithName("SHARKNODE")?.position.x < -10 {
        foreground.childNodeWithName("SHARKNODE")?.xScale =  -1
        foreground.childNodeWithName("SHARKNODE")?.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = CGFloat(50)
    }else if (foreground.childNodeWithName("SHARKNODE")?.position.x > self.size.width + 10) {
            foreground.childNodeWithName("SHARKNODE")?.xScale = 1
            foreground.childNodeWithName("SHARKNODE")?.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = CGFloat(-50)
    }

}


func createLeftButton () {
    let button = UIButton();
    button.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.width - self.frame.width, 0, self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height) // X, Y, width, height

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameScene.buttonPressedRight(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view!.addSubview(button)
    button.layer.zPosition = -1

}

func createRightButton () {

    let buttonRight = UIButton();

    buttonRight.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.width / 2, 0, self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height) // X, Y, width, height

    buttonRight.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameScene.buttonPressedLeft(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view!.addSubview(buttonRight)
    buttonRight.layer.zPosition = -1
}

func createLeftButtonFirst () {
    leftButtonFirst = UIButton()
    leftButtonFirst.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.width - self.frame.width, 0, self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height) // X, Y, width, height

    leftButtonFirst.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameScene.buttonPressedLeftFirst(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view!.addSubview(leftButtonFirst)
    leftButtonFirst.layer.zPosition = 1
}

func createRightButtonFirst () {

    rightButtonFirst = UIButton()
    rightButtonFirst.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.width / 2, 0, self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height) // X, Y, width, height
    rightButtonFirst.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameScene.buttonPressedRightFirst(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view!.addSubview(rightButtonFirst)
    rightButtonFirst.userInteractionEnabled = true
    rightButtonFirst.layer.zPosition = 1

}


func buttonPressedRight(sender: UIButton!) {

    if player.physicsBody?.velocity.dx > 0 {
       player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: -200, dy:  player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy)
 }

    player.xScale = -1
}
func buttonPressedLeft(sender: UIButton!) {
    if player.physicsBody?.velocity.dx < 0 {
        player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 200, dy:  player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy)
    }
    player.xScale = 1

}
func buttonPressedLeftFirst(sender: UIButton!) {
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: -200, dy:  player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy)

    player.xScale = -1

    rightButtonFirst.hidden = true
    leftButtonFirst.hidden = true
}

func buttonPressedRightFirst(sender: UIButton!) {
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 200, dy:  player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy)
    player.xScale = 1

    rightButtonFirst.hidden = true
    leftButtonFirst.hidden = true
}
}
```

**GameElements.swift:**

```
 import SpriteKit

 extension GameScene {


func createBackground() -> SKNode{
    let backgroundNode = SKNode()
    let spacing = 32 * scaleFactor

    for index in 0 ... 20 {

        let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: String(format: "Background/Background%02d", index + 1))
        node.setScale(scaleFactor)
        node.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
        node.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y:spacing * CGFloat(index))
        node.size.width = self.frame.width

        backgroundNode.addChild(node)
    }

    return backgroundNode
}


func createMidground () -> SKNode{

let midgroundNode = SKNode()
var anchor: CGPoint!
var xPos: CGFloat!

for index in 0 ... 250 {
    var name: String

    let randomNumber = arc4random() % 2

    if randomNumber > 0 {
        name = "whale"
        anchor = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        xPos = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(170) + 15)
    } else{
        name = "whale"
        anchor = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
        xPos = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(170) + 15)
    }
    let cloudNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: name)
    cloudNode.alpha = 0.3
    cloudNode.anchorPoint = anchor
    cloudNode.position = CGPoint(x: xPos, y: 500 + 500 * CGFloat(index))
    midgroundNode.addChild(cloudNode)

}
    return midgroundNode

}

func createPlayer() -> SKNode {

let playerNode = SKNode()
    playerNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: 80)

    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player")
    playerNode.addChild(sprite)

    playerNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sprite.size.width / 2)

    playerNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    playerNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

    playerNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    playerNode.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    playerNode.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    playerNode.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0

    playerNode.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

    playerNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionBitMask.Player

    playerNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    playerNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionBitMask.Bubble | CollisionBitMask.Shark

    return playerNode

}



func createSharkAtPosition (position:CGPoint, ofType type:SharkType) -> SharkNode {

    let shark = SharkNode()
    let position = CGPoint(x: position.x * scaleFactor, y: position.y)
    shark.position = position
    shark.name = "SHARKNODE"
    shark.sharkType = type

    let spriteTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shark1")
    let spriteTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shark2")
    let spriteTexture3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shark3")

    let sharkAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([spriteTexture1, spriteTexture2, spriteTexture3], timePerFrame: 0.2)
    let makeSharkFlap = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sharkAnimation)

    sharkSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: spriteTexture1)
    sharkSprite.runAction(makeSharkFlap)
    shark.addChild(sharkSprite)


    shark.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sharkSprite.size)
    shark.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    shark.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    shark.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionBitMask.Shark
    shark.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    shark.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(-60, 0)

    return shark
}



func createPlatformAtPosition (position:CGPoint, ofType type:PlatformType) -> PlatformNode {

    let node = PlatformNode()
    let position = CGPoint(x: position.x * scaleFactor, y: position.y)
    node.position = position
    node.name = "PLATFORMNODE"
    node.platformType = type
    var sprite:SKSpriteNode

    sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bubble")

    node.addChild(sprite)

    node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sprite.size.height / 2)
    node.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionBitMask.Bubble
    node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

    return node
}
```

}

Comment: Anyone got any information on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`childNodeWithName` only calls the first child node with name, you need to enumerate through all of them

```
func sharkWall(){
    foreground.enumerateChildNodesWithName("SHARKNODE"){
        node, stop in 
        if node.position.x < -10 {
            node.xScale =  -1
            node.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = CGFloat(50)
        }else if (node.position.x > self.size.width + 10) {
            node.xScale = 1
            node.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = CGFloat(-50)
        }
    }
}
```